# I can no longer git push to github: error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

Since Yesterday I can no longer git push my work.

when I push, it starts pushing and after less than a minute it gives me this error in intellij

```
Push failed Delta compression using up to 4 threads Total 260 (delta 20), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted the remote end hung up unexpectedly the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Github Desktop gives me:

```
Writing objects: 100% (259/259), 15.10 MiB | 9.98 MiB/s                         
Writing objects: 100% (259/259), 15.81 MiB | 8.97 MiB/s, done.
Total 259 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I try using git bash the same happens and I get this error

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 270, done.
Counting objects: 100% (270/270), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (243/243), done.
Writing objects: 100% (260/260), 15.81 MiB | 10.94 MiB/s, done.
Total 260 (delta 20), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. It is better suited to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: do you know the solution though?

Comment: Nop. You have a better chance to get an answer if you move your question to one of those other forums, hence my previous comment.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Turns out it was just a bad internet connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOW, I disconnect from my ADSL which has a very low upload speed and connected through my phone internet which has a decent upload speed. the push was successful. seriously why the hell is this is even a thing. so people with low upload speed are screwed.